# How to change axes titles of ROC curve in package mada?

Tags: r

Consider the code below to draw an ROC curve:

```
library(mada)
data(AuditC)
fit.reitsma <- reitsma(AuditC)
plot(fit.reitsma)
```

This code sets the vertical and horizontal axes titles to "Sensitivity" and "False Positive Rate" respectively by default. I tried to change the titles using the code below:

```
plot(fit.reitsma, xlab="Specifity")
```

But this gives the error:

```
Error in plot.default(c(2, 2), ylim = ylim, xlim = xlim, xlab = "False Positive Rate",  :
formal argument "xlab" matched by multiple actual arguments
```

Seems it does not give permission to change the titles. Any clues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using the step-by step plot will allow you to change the axes. If you follow along the example in the README of  `reitsma-class {mada}`

```
#calculate a SROC curve
my.sroc <- sroc(fit.reitsma)
# calculate a confidence region but do not plot it
my.cr <- ROCellipse(fit.reitsma)
# plot the confidence region in ROC space as a line
plot(my.cr$ROCellipse, type = "l", xlim = c(0,1), ylim = c(0,1),  xlab="Specificity", ylab="Sensitivity")
lines(my.sroc)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. This works well. Now do you have any idea how to add the prediction region to the plot? I know that the fitted values for that can be saved by `f = fit.reitsma$fitted.values`, but have no idea how to use it.

Comment: I'd just take the outputs outside of mada as a dataframe and use ggplot2.